# Use google query as an array formula to sum values in a column based on information in another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have 2 tabs needing worked with. The first tab, `market_pull` has a function that pulls information from EVE Online's ESI and sorts the information into several columns:

```
duration  | is_buy_order  | issued   |  location_id  |   min_volume  |  order_id   |    price  |    range  |    type_id  |  volume_remain  |    volume_total
```

The second tab, `bulk_market_data` sorts the information into several columns:

```
Citadel ID  |  Item Id  |  Item Name  |  Volume Ea  |  Qty Available    |  Lowest Price |  Total Volume | Jita Sell |  ISK Difference   |  % Difference
```

I need help with the `bulk_market_data` tab. I need to use the `Item Id` column from `bulk_market_data` as a criteria to compare to `market_pull` the column `type_id` pull the MIN value from the corresponding row in the `price` column.

I need to do essentially the same thing except I need to use the `Item Id` column from `bulk_market_data` as a criteria to compare to `market_pull` the column `type_id` pull the total SUM value from the all the corresponding rows in the `volume_remain` column.

I'm using array formulas because in the `bulk_market_data` tab there is about 10,000 rows and when I had a formula in every row for every column the sheet slowed down drastically. Thank you for your time and [**HERE**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzJiDGbFKFMvx4yTuZaEzjMMSGNNANbVlCC94zNYEbs/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample spreadsheet with the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in F4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4:C, QUERY({market_pull!C4:C, market_pull!J4:K}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null and Col1 = FALSE group by Col2"), 2, 0)))
```

use in G4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C4:C="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(C4:C, SORT(QUERY({market_pull!C4:J}, 
 "select Col8,Col6 where Col1 = FALSE"), 1, 1, 2, 1), 2, 0), 0)))
```

use in H4:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C4:C="",,ROUNDUP(IF(
 E4:E1004*F4:F1004=0,,E4:E1004*F4:F1004), 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you so much :D I noticed one thing that was my fault, is there a way to edit the function in F4 to add the extra criteria that `market_pullC:C = FALSE` ? I tried playing with it but I'm not sure how to convert what you set up without changing the vlookup.